# Mechanize::Formの動的に生成されるメソッドに関するドキュメント

Tags: ruby, mechanize

`Mechanize::Form`では以下のように`name`要素での指定と等価の事が動的に生成されるメソッドでも実現できるようですが、それに関する記述はドキュメントのどこにあるのでしょうか？

```
agent.get(login_url).form_with(action: '/foo/login.do') do |f|
  f.username = 'username'
  # f.field_with(name: 'username').value = 'username' と等価？
  f.password = 'password'
end.click_button
```

http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Form.html

を探してみたのですが説明があるのかどうか自分にはわかりませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こういう動的にメソッドが作られるものは [`method_missing`](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Form.html#method-i-method_missing) を探すといいかもしれません。

> Treat form fields like accessors.

ソースを開いて実装を見れば期待通りの内容だと思います。

あとは、[GUIDE](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_rdoc.html#label-Filling+Out+Forms)のこの記述かな。

> but the most convenient is that you can access input fields as accessors on the object.